# How to remove only the first group of a pattern?

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I have tried a number of ways to approach this but I'm out of ideas. Hopefully someone out there can point out what I am doing wrong.

Here is my input:

```
<Root>
    <A>Keep</A>
    <B>Keep</B>
    <B>Remove</B>
    <B>Keep</B>
    <C>Keep</C>
</Root>
```

As you can kinda figure out by now, I'm just trying to remove line #4:

```
<Root>
    <A>Keep</A>
    <B>Keep</B>
    <B>Keep</B>
    <C>Keep</C>
</Root>
```

Here is what I have so far, but it's not quite working as intended:

```
sed -e '3,${g;s/<B>.*<\/B>//p}' t1
```

I tried adding part of the group logic that I found around but it's not working as it seems that sed has no direct way of making it greedy.

Any ideas?

Comment: 1. in the traditional understanding of things, sed is problematically greedy. 2. why not just `sed '/Remove/d' t1` ? 3. Using `3,$` seems a cheat: if that, then why not `sed -n '4!' t1` ? 4. you reg ex `/s/<B>.../` doesn't even mention `Remove`, can you have a following `<B>` line after the `Remove` line? OR you're not really telling us everything important about your problem ;-) Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Hopefully someone out there can point out what I am doing wrong

The right way is to use XML/HTML parsers like **`xmlstarlet`** or **`xmllint`**:

```
xmlstarlet ed -O -d "//Root/*[3]" input.xml
```

- `ed` - edit mode
- `-O` - omit XML declaration `(<?xml ...?>)`
- `-d` - delete action
- `"//Root/*[3]"` - *xpath* expression selecting the 3rd child node of the parent node `Root`

---

The output:

```
<Root>
  <A>Keep</A>
  <B>Keep</B>
  <B>Keep</B>
  <C>Keep</C>
</Root>
```